# pthread_join and void** - error understanding

Tags: c, compiler-errors, pthreads, pthread-join

I wrote a simple task like the following. It prints a string, increments the global variable glob, and returns its value, through the pthread_exit, to the pthread_join.

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <pthread.h>

int glob = 0;

void *task()
{
    printf("I am a simple thread.\n");
    glob++;
    pthread_exit((void*)&glob);
}

int main()
{
pthread_t   tid;
int         create = 1;
void        **ppvglob;


    create = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, task, NULL);
    if (create != 0)    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    
    pthread_join(tid, ppvglob);
    
    int **ppv = (int**)ppvglob;
    printf("Variabile globale restituita alla terminazione del thread: %d\n", **ppv);                   
    
    return(0);
}
```

The compiler gives me the error:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:29:2: warning: ‘ppvglob’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   29 |  pthread_join(tid, ppvglob);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Could you tell me the reason please?

Comment: Your pthread callback should have the format `void* f (void*)` and nothing else. Functions that return a value must actually `return` it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing:

> ```
> pthread_join(tid, ppvglob);
> ```

because you never initialized *ppvglob* it is normal the compiler protest, but in fact you must replace:

> ```
> void        **ppvglob;
> ....
> pthread_join(tid, ppvglob);
> ```

by:

> ```
> void        *pvglob;
> ....
> pthread_join(tid, &pvglob);
> ```

then of course:

> ```
> int **ppv = (int**)ppvglob;
> printf("Variabile globale restituita alla terminazione del thread: %d\n", **ppv);
> ```

by:

> ```
> int *pv = (int*)pvglob;
> printf("Variabile globale restituita alla terminazione del thread: %d\n", *pv);
> ```

---

So having:

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <pthread.h>

int glob = 0;

void *task()
{
    printf("I am a simple thread.\n");
    glob++;
    pthread_exit((void*)&glob);
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t   tid;
  int         create = 1;
  void        *pvglob;


  create = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, task, NULL);
  if (create != 0)    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    
  pthread_join(tid, &pvglob);
    
  int *pv = (int*)pvglob;
  printf("Variabile globale restituita alla terminazione del thread: %d\n", *pv);                   
    
  return(0);
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
% gcc -Wall c.c -lpthread
% ./a.out
I am a simple thread.
Variabile globale restituita alla terminazione del thread: 1
```

that print 1 because this is the value of *glob*

Comment: Hello @bruno, could you explain me how come &pvglob is initialized please? I never used it before and the pthread_exit returns a void*, instead &pvglob is a void**. Maybe the pthread_exit inside makes a convertion from void* to void** and pass it to the pthread_join?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi *pvglob* is set with the exit status of
       the target thread (i.e., the value that the target thread supplied to
       pthread_exit), if the
       target thread was canceled, then by PTHREAD_CANCELED ( see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html ). So in your case you will get the value of *glob*

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi there is no conversion from `void**` to `void*`, the second argument of `pthread_join` is a pointer to allow the function to set the value, in that case the pointer point to a `void*` because this is the type return by the toplevel function of the thread / set by `pthread_exit`. Supposing the toplevel function of a thread return an `int` and then `pthread_exit` get an `int` to be consistent then `pthread_join` has to get a `int*`

Comment: I've only a doubt: why does the compiler tell that the ‘ppvglob’ may be used uninitialized? It is uninitialized because i never used it before.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi it is uninitialized because you use its value before to set it. `void        **ppvglob;` defines *ppvglob* without initializing it. In case it is a global variable it is initialized by NULL by default, but in your case it is a local variable so no default initialization

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi but giving its address (`&pvglob`) its value is not used at that level and the fact it is not initialized is not relevant => no warning

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_join()` has a `void **` parameter because it needs to *update* an
existing `void *`.
It is the same logic as providing and `int *` to `scanf("%d", ...)`: to update an existing `int` you need to provide its address.
In the general case, when a C function has to update an existing `Type`,
then it needs a `Type *` parameter.

In any case, you don't just declare an uninitialised `Type *` but
provide the address (`&`) of an existing `Type`.
So here, you need to take the address of an existing `void *` so that
the parameter is initialised to a location where a `void *` actually stands.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to have a `void *`...

```
void * glob;
```

...and to pass its *address* to `pthread_join()` so the function can make it point to the "return" value...

```
pthread_join(tid, &glob);
```

This "making it point to the 'return' value" requires `pthread_join()` to *dereference* its parameter...

```
*glob = /* whatever */;
```

...so that *your* `glob` will have changed it's value.

What *you* did was declaring...

```
void ** glob;
```

...which means that your call of...

```
pthread_join(tid, glob);
```

...will pass an *uninitialized* value to `pthread_join()` (making dereferencing it undefined behavior), and also mean that your `glob` will *remain* uninitialized, making your...

```
int **ppv = (int**)ppvglob;
printf("Variabile globale restituita alla terminazione del thread: %d\n", **ppv);
```

...undefined behavior as well.

This should work:

```
void * glob;

/* ... */

pthread_join(tid, &glob);

int * v = (int*)glob;
printf("Variabile globale restituita alla terminazione del thread: %d\n", *v);
```

---

(And, please pretty please, don't use [System Hungarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_Hungarian_vs._Apps_Hungarian) notation... it's so bad even Microsoft stopped using it...)